# ¿Cómo negar un <bean:write > en struts?

Tags: java, jsp, booleano, struts

Tengo un [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) que utiliza scriptlets y quiero cambiar eso, pero el *scriptlet* que quiero cambiar es:

`readonly="<%=!editable%>"`

`readonly` es un atributo, `editable` es una variabe de tipo boolean definida en otro scriptlet en el mismo jsp y como se puede ver la están negando.

Esperaba poder hacer algo así:
`readonly='<bean:write name="!editable">'` pero como era de esperar no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes utilizar [Expression Language (EL)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html). Es decir:

```
readonly="${!editable}"
```

Otra alternativa con EL sería:

```
readonly="${not editable}"
```

Puedes ver la lista completa de operadores admitidos [aquí](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html).